# Pocket Overflow: Stack Overflow in your pocket

Tags: app, placeholder

#### About:

This is a sample app to consult Stack Overflow and more generally Stack Exchange sites.
I was using the original site app but, after resetting my iPhone I lost it, so decided to do one by myself.

Currently, it is only a reader, with search and cache capabilities.
In each post there is a link to open it in browser, if you want to reply, add comment, ... That is how I currently use it.

#### Screenshot / Code Snippet:

https://pocketoverflow.000webhostapp.com/images/iPhone12mini-text-help.png

#### Download / Install:

The app is available in AppStore: https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/pocketoverflow/id1640707675

Web site: https://pocketoverflow.000webhostapp.com
(work in progress ...)

#### Platform:

App runs on iPhone (iOS 15.5+), iPad (iPadOS 15.5+), Mac M1 (macOS 12.3+)

#### Contact:

Created by P'tit Xav.

You can contact by mail: pocket.overflow@gmx.com

#### License: (optional)

Currently free with no ad.

May be I will add, tip IAP if people want to help me.

#### Code:

Uses Swift, SwiftUI (+ Combine)
No third party framework.
Thanks to Stack Overflow community, I could find useful help in some posts.

#### Versions:

- 1.0
- initial version
- 1.1
- User can save questions, answers.
- Direct access to user questions, answers and comments.
- For help in icons tap the .
- 1.2
- Some animation for help
- Cache management improved
- Clean cache button
- Access to question from answer/comment
- 1.3
- correct bug that kept same questions when popping back views
- 1.4
- change app name on springboard, but it may "overflow"
- possibility to see number of unread messages and notifications
- the app now remember on which tab you were.

Comment: "[Stack Overflow](https://stackapps.com/legal/trademark-guidance)" and "Stack Exchange" (the last section), not "StackOverflow" or "StackExchange". See also *[Naming guidelines](https://stackoverflow.design/brand/copywriting/naming/)*.

Comment: This app is named "PocketOverflow" (without space) in the App Store, but after it is installed, it's name is "MySO" (name of the icon and name of the app in the settings). Can you correct this? Also can you add notifications on your app? This is primarily why I searched a replacement app for the now defunct official app.

Comment: When do you want notifications ? When something comes in your mailbox for example ?

Comment: +1 for getting inbox notifications. I installed the app today and I see questions etc; but the inbox remains empty, and every time I switch to this view, the ligthning bolt icon for network status changes to "not connected" so I see no messages. (At the time of writing I have four unread messages in my inbox.) This functionality was the sole reason I installed the app - the now defunct official app used to provide this, but obviously no longer works.

Comment: @PtitXav Yes, I logged in and it shows my reputation correctly, though I can't see my avatar (I'm guessing it doesn't try to?) When I switch to the main (posts) view the connection bolt immediately changes to indicate that I'm online. iPhone 12 mini, latest IOS (16.3.1)

Comment: @tripleee : i Aldo see my avatar disappeared after reinstalling. I will check. BTW , I still can see my inbox even if no avatar (I see your message in it). I’m in testing a new version. If you want to test it before it’s release you can ask at the contact mail.

Comment: @tripleee : You may need to kill/restart the app to see your avatar.

Comment: Thanks, the first restart lost my login info entirely, but logging in and then restarting the app again finally brought in my avatar. Still no inbox, though (on the regular site I had three inbox notifications, all from this post.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144710/discussion-between-ptit-xav-and-tripleee).

Comment: @tripleee : what happens when you tap on your a avatar on top right corner ? I saw a glitch that you may need to reselect the site (tap on middle of top bar) for the button to actually respond.

Comment: @PtitXav It shows an empty inbox. If I select one of the other tabs on the bottom bar, it correctly displays my questions, my comments, etc.